# Binding related control from ASP.NET markup

Tags: asp.net, binding, custom-controls, markup, typeconverter

I have a control that looks along the lines of this:

```
public class MyControl : Control
{
   [Bindable(true)]
   public MyControl MyControlParent { get; set; }
   // snip
}
```

In my markup I want the following:

```
<tag:MyControl ID="foo" runat="server">
   <tag:MyControl ID="bar" MyControlParent="foo" runat="server"></tag:MyControl>
</tag:MyControl>
```

The reason for me wanting to be able to name a parent like this is because I would also like to be able to do something like this:
    
       
          
       
    
or

```
<tag:MyControl ID="foo" runat="server">
    <tag:MyControl ID="foobar" runat="server">
       <tag:MyControl ID="bar" MyControlParent="foo" runat="server"></tag:MyControl>
    </tag:MyControl>
</tag:MyControl>
```

or

```
<tag:MyControl ID="foo" runat="server"></tag:MyControl>
<!-- snip -->
<tag:MyControl ID="bar" MyControlParent="foo" runat="server"></tag:MyControl>
```

I've tried adding a type converter, but it fires before HttpContext.Current.Handler is set which means I can't search the page controls for the desired MyControl instance. Parent-child relationship in this control imparts certain inheritance of property values and doesn't (read shouldn't) necessarily imply a parent-child relationship in the control tree.

Is there a (practical) solution to this problem or am I just wanting more than is possible right now? =)

Cheers
// Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic issue with your code is that you are setting the MyControlParent property to the **ID** of the parent control not to the control itself, yet the property is declared with type MyControl. It would be OK to change the type of your property to a string, and then, elsewhere in your code, look up the actual control from the ID.

Comment: That would be a solution. But I don't think it's quite as nice and clean to do it this way, unless you can hide MyControlParent from the markup and MyControlParentID from code behind. I'm looking into that solution, and if it pans out I'll mark yours as answer. Thanks and cheers!

Comment: While I'm not very happy with the solution I thank you for the answer! =) I somehow feel robbed of a nice feature. It was easy enough to make MyControlParent non-bindable from the markup, but I still haven't found a way to hide MyControlParentID in the code behind. This was expected because it would probably be weird to have a property not available from the CB, even if it would make the code nicer, in my opinion anyway ^_^ Cheers!